# Method for restoring in app purchases is unlocking features that hadn't been purchased

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

I have a nonconsumable IAP for a "Save Feature."  It was recently rejected because I did not include a restore feature in the app. I added code for restoring, but when I created a new test user that hadn't purchased the app and pressed the restore button, the save feature was unlocked.

Here is how I check if a user has purchased the save feature

```
 if (![userDefaults boolForKey:@"isPurchase"]){
        [self purchaseMyProduct:[validProducts objectAtIndex:0]];
    }
    else { ... }
```

These are the methods I added to restore IAP's.

```
- (void)restorePurchases { //called when button pressed

    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]restoreCompletedTransactions];

}

- (void)paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue {

    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in queue.transactions) {
        NSString *productID = transaction.payment.productIdentifier;

        if ([productID isEqualToString:@"facePuppetsSave"]) {
            NSLog(@"called");
            NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
            [userDefaults setBool:YES forKey:@"isPurchase"];
            [userDefaults synchronize];
        }
    }          
}
```

Here are the methods I already had.

```
 -(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue
updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions {
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions) {
        switch (transaction.transactionState) {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing:
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                if ([transaction.payment.productIdentifier
                     isEqualToString:@"facePuppetsSave"]) {

                    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
                    [userDefaults setBool:YES forKey:@"isPurchase"];
                    [userDefaults synchronize];

                    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:
                                              @"Purchase completed. Saving now available." message:nil delegate:
                                              self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
                    [alertView show];
                    [alertView release];
                }
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                NSLog(@"Restored ");
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}


-(void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request
    didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
{
    SKProduct *validProduct = nil;
    int count = [response.products count];
    if (count>0) {


        validProducts = response.products;
        [validProducts retain];
        validProduct = [response.products objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

Also, for the new test user example, I noticed that the NSLog "called" from the `paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished` method is being called twice and "restored" from the `paymentQueue:updatedTransactions:` method is not being called at all.

How can I modify my code to restore properly?

Comment: How did you run your test? Deleted the app first? Logged out of the other account first?

Comment: I deleted, Product >> clean on xcode, and signed out. Not entirely sure about the order

Comment: Also, I should have mentioned that it worked fine the first time, but not the second time. That is, when I first tapped "restore purchase" and then tried saving, it asked me to buy the IAP. Then I tapped "restore purchase" again, and the save feature became unlocked.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this:
     #pragma mark SKPaymentTransactionOBserver

```
  - (void)storeRestoreTransactionsFinished:(NSNotification*)notification
  {
NSLog(@"- (void)storeRestoreTransactionsFinished:(NSNotification*)notification");
[apDelegate hideLoading];
  }

  - (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
  {
for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions) {
    switch (transaction.transactionState) {
        case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing:
            NSLog(@"Prossing.............");

            break;

        case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
        {

            [self completeTransaction:transaction];
            NSError* error;
            NSDictionary* jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization
                                  JSONObjectWithData:transaction.transactionReceipt

                                  options:kNilOptions 
                                  error:&error];
            NSLog(@"JSON Receipt: %@",jsonDict);

            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:jsonDict forKey:@"A"];
            NSLog(@"Purchase was a Success.....");
        }
            break;
        case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:

            [self failedTransaction:transaction];

            NSLog(@"Purchase cancelled");


            break;

        case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:

            [self restoreTransaction:transaction];

            default:

            break;
       }         
    }
 }
  - (void)restoreTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction {
NSLog(@"restoreTransaction...");

[self validateReceiptForTransaction:transaction];
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
 }
 - (void)paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue
 {
 NSLog(@"Restore completed transactions finished.");
 NSLog(@" Number of transactions in queue: %d", [[queue transactions] count]);
 for (SKPaymentTransaction *trans in [queue transactions])
 {
    NSLog(@" transaction id %@ for product %@.", [trans transactionIdentifier], [[trans      payment] productIdentifier]);
    NSLog(@" original transaction id: %@ for product %@.", [[trans originalTransaction] transactionIdentifier],
          [[[trans originalTransaction] payment]productIdentifier]);


    if ([[[trans payment] productIdentifier] isEqual:       kMDPulseSubscriptionProductIdentifier]) {

        NSLog(@"Purchase Restored");

        // Do your stuff to unlock
      }
  }
}


- (void)restoreCompletedTransactions
{
    NSLog(@"Restore Tapped in transaction process");
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
}
```